# How to activate a single div using React.js and setActive?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I am currently creating an app that has three menu tabs, each of which is being represented by an accordion with a menu title and content. Currently, when clicking on the title the content divs appear relative to whatever is in the box. I want to click on each menu title and have the content div of that menu appear in isolation, triggering the active state of that particular div.

The toggle accordion function that I have created opens all the content windows. When clicking any of the menu titles, all of the content displays.

This is my function, simplified:

```
function PlayerApp(props) {

  const [setActive, setActiveState] = useState("");
  const [setHeight, setHeightState] = useState("0px");

  const content = useRef(null);

  function toggleAccordion() { 

    setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "");

    setHeightState(
      setActive === "active" ? "0px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`
    );
  }

  return (

  <div className="content"> 

    <div className="content-list">
      
       <div ref={content} style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }} className="accordion__content">
       <div className="accordion__text"> text content here </div>

       </div>
      </div>

      <div className="content-list">
        
        <div ref={content} style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }} className="accordion__content">
        <div className="accordion__text"> text here </div>

       </div>
      </div>

      <div className="content-list">

        <div ref={content} style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }} className="accordion__content">
        <div className="accordion__text"> text content her </div>

       </div>

      </div>

        <div className="content-title">
          <button className={`menu_title1 ${setActive}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
            <p className="accordion__title">Menu 1:</p>
            </button>
        </div>

          <div className="content-title">
          <button className={`menu_title2 ${setActive}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
            <p className="accordion__title">Menu 2:</p>
            </button>
        </div>
           <div className="content-title">
          <button className={`menu_title3 ${setActive}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
            <p className="accordion__title">Menu 3:</p>
            </button>
        </div>

        </div>

  );
}

export default PlayerApp;
```

Despite having unique names for each of my button classes, clicking on that class still triggers the active state for all of those divs.

How do I alter my function so that clicking on each button renders a unique response for that accordion window?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually cleanup your code by creating an array with menu details.

```
  const accordionItems = [
    { id: 'menu1', text: 'Menu 1' },
    { id: 'menu2', text: 'Menu 2' },
    { id: 'menu3', text: 'Menu 3' },
  ];
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState();
```

and the html will be like

```
 {accordionItems.map((p, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="content-title">
              <button
                className={`menu_title1 ` + (activeItem === p.id ? 'active' : '')}
                onClick={() => {
                  setActiveItem(p.id);
                }}
              >
                <p className="accordion__title">{p.text}</p>
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Comment: struggling to integrate this into my code and juggle my other functions, it seems when I try and replace the content-title it disappears from my screen